# Android app wont run in android studio emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have writed couple simple apps in android studio, I normally run/test them on my phone via USB, but I would like to use emulator (access to internet which i dont have on phone). My emulator starts normally but app wont show/run. There is no error or nothing. Many people writes about how emulators run slowly, my emulator starts fast and i've waited 10 mins and still no signs of my app. I've tryied different devices in AVD but nothing worked, any suggestions/ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: It's quite hard to help you without any error.

Comment: i've noticed that after emulator starts, the red frame flashaes on screen like something was trying to launch but nothing happens, there is no error

Answer (score 1):

Try genymotion, it's pretty smooth emulator(much faster than standard implementation) using virtual box. Just install, add virtual device and its ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

Run AVD and after press Shift+F10 (RUN APP) And wait for load your app to AVD.

Comment: that didn't help, I've noticed that after emulator starts, the red frame flashes on screen of AVD like something was trying to launch but failed, there is no error...

Comment: can you give a screenshot

Comment: it was hard to catch it, because it flashes like for 0.25sec but here you can clearly see the red frame while launching apps in AVD http://postimg.org/image/x2mf5enqb/

Comment: maybe hard for your pc?

Comment: hard what? hard to run app on my pc? dont think so... got intel i7, emulator runs smoothly, but it dont run my app!

Comment: so you should remove & install AS!